# When was the name of Wales first attested in Romanian, and in which form?

Tags: translation, transliteration, romanian

As a native speaker, I am amazed that in Romanian the name of Wales, when it was introduced, very probably in the 19th century, was translated as *Ţara Galilor*, literally "Country of the **Gauls**", unlike in any other European country — where, instead, we find either

- the English form "Wales" (Slavic and German languages, Hungarian, Baltic, Albanian), or
- a Latinized version of the name similar to the French *Galles* (*Pays de Galles*, where *Galles* is not a [plural](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/40426/3728), like in Romanian, but the transposition of the term Wales, I think; see this answer on [how Wales/Welsh have evolved in English](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/519123/70248)).

I have initially asked a related question on the history site which then was moved here: [Excepting Romanian, was "Wales" ever translated in modern times outside English with the same term as that meaning "Gaul" or "Gauls"?](https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/q/34245/27251).

The term *Ţara Galilor* is also odd in that it has a rather archaic form, without many precedents. It follows the old structure of the Romanian endonym of Wallachia, *Ţara Romanească* (literally "Romanian Country"), applied in the past to other countries, but which is not applied *now* to any modern name of a country or state, except Wales: it survives only in the archaic/poetic naming of old regions of Romania, especially from Transilvania, like *Ţara Lăpuşului, Ţara Oaşului* (for Lăpuş/Oaş regions), in the historical name of [*The Lower Countries*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low_Countries) (*Ţările de jos*) and in the name of the *Tierra del Fuego* (*Ţara de Foc*)

---

Repeating from my other post:

*My scenario about what happened* is that at a stage when the common knowledge on the Great Britain was somewhat fuzzy, Romanian journalists translated *Pays de Galles* as *Ţara Galilor*; at that time there was no word for Welsh in Romanian, but there was already one for Gaul, which had been constructed *directly from Latin*, in the form *gal*. But when the same type of people were looking for a Romanian translation for Wales/Welsh they could not use Latin and so used French, where the term for Welsh is *gallois*, while for Gaul it is *gaulois*; but they neglected the 1-letter difference and considered those terms as identical. As *Gaul* already existed in Romanian as *gal*, they simply transposed into Romanian the false identity between *gallois* and *gaulois*. This was not done because they were aware of or interested in the common origin of those two terms, but because their French was not perfect. The erroneous translation entered the common use and even dictionaries: but the only dictionary that I could find where "gal"/"gali", meaning Gaul/Gauls, is used for "modern inhabitants of Wales" (with an example for *the Prince of Wales* as "*principele Galilor*", that is "the Prince of the Gauls") dates from 1923. As far as I know, in later dictionaries the error was *partially corrected*: Welsh became *galez/galezi* - fem. *galeză/galeze* (similar to other Romance languages), but the name of the country still reflects the old mishap.

---

Other hypotheses can be imagined:

- a cross-contamination from Greek and French into Romanian: in Greek, where the name of Gaul is *Γαλατία,* the name of *Wales* is *Ουαλία*,  which might have seemed close to the Latin *Gallia*, and thus encourage a confusion between *Welsh* and *Gauls*.
- an ignorant reader of the French terms "Prince de Galles" or "Pays de Galles" who barely understood French but knew the recent Romanian word *gal* for Gaul, could have translated "de Galles" as "of the Gauls".
- the influence of the (somewhat dubious) theory of  "Popular Wallachias" (or "Romanias"): Romanian Wikipedia page [here](https://ro.wikipedia.org/wiki/Romanii_populare), in French [here](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Valachie), while the English linked page doesn't follow the same content. The theory is a bit more complex, but basically it tries to name "Wallachia" (or more or less vaguely relate to that) any region which at some time or other was called with a term based on the German root `walaz` meaning non-German, then Celtic, Roman, neo-Latin, Italian, Romanian. As on the [odd map of those half-imaginary entities](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Imper-Barbar.jpg#/media/Fi%C8%99ier:Imper-Barbar.jpg) Wales is also mentioned (because its name is based on that same root), while Gaul is named *Walha*, and given that the form `Ţara...` is also traditionally used for [Romanian old regions, some of which are identified in this "theory" with one "Wallachia" or other](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:TransylvaniaEthnography_ro.png#/media/Fi%C8%99ier:TransylvaniaEthnography_ro.png), a such influence could have contributed to the creation or at least to the conservation of the form *Ţara Galilor*, as it encourages both the use of the old/odd form *Ţara...* and the identification between Wales and Gaul/"Walha".
- in the context of any of the above, the [common origin of all the terms involved here - the old German root naming foreigners](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Walhaz) (the fact that Galles/Wales, Welsh, Gallois, Gaulois, Waloon, Wallachian, etc have the same root) could have acted as a facilitator, although obviously the common *origin* doesn't change their very different *meaning*.

My idea is that this error was made rather recently, sometime between 1830 and 1890. But I do not know exactly when.

Comment: **Considering down-voting: please leave a comment (I *am* a new contributor): let me know what's wrong, whether the question is off-topic,  etc.**

Comment: The question is precise. It's well written, and the lack of own research might be excusable, if finding references proofs exceptionally difficult. The rules prohibit language specific "grammar and usage" questions, to which onomastics is counted by some. But you didn't move the Q here (judges should feel bound by jurisprudent referals). It's not language specific, if your hypothesis is in question with regards to methodology. There's a comparative element, and this could go a long way.

Comment: @vectory - The question (the one in title) would fit which stackexchange site do you think?

Comment: it would rumanian.SE, which does not exist I don't think

Comment: @vectory - maybe some Romanian archivist or historian stumbles into this. I guess it's off-topic on Hystory  SE. The linked question was moved here.

Comment: [Has any 19th century author used the term “Galles” for “Gauls” except Étienne Pivert de Senancour in “Obermann”?](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/40440/3728)

Comment: How is this not a duplicate of https://linguistics.stackexchange.com/questions/34245/excepting-romanian-was-wales-ever-translated-transliterated-in-modern-times-o? Reduce this question to that which is new.

Comment: @user6726 - :) — If by "this" you mean the question under which we comment:(A) If you give me an answer to only one of them, you'll see that you haven't answered the other. (B) If you answer to both, the answers cannot be identical. (C) If you don't give me an answer, I'll say this: the above is asking *"when did X happened in Y"?*, the other is asking *"did ever X happened anywhere **except** Y?"*. See? — Now, if by "this" you mean the Q linked in my previous comment, (A) and (B) still apply.

Comment: @user6726 - please give me some details on why you think the questions are more than just linked.

Comment: I don't think there's anything of linguistic value here, it's just asking about the history of a single word. We can't do linguistics on arbitrary words, but only on language systems.

Comment: @curiousdannii - I have to agree. But I had to try because I cannot find a good place where to ask this question for the moment. A SE for Romanian language is absent.

Comment: g/w alternation in Romance/Germanic is not "transliteration", it's a regular sound change. you see it in guerra vs. werra/war, guilherme/wilheim, guarda/warden, and many others. Gaul, Galles, Wales are all **the same word**, namely Germanic \*walhaz, subjected to various local sound changes. This has nothing to do with writing, inscriptions, or scribes; it’s a normal phenomenon of language change, done in speech, just like e.g. Romance /p/ corresponds to Germanic /f/. There is nothing special at all in the Romanian name of Wales; everybody calls them \*walhaz, subject to local sound changes.

Comment: @melissa_boiko - +vote for the "transliteration" part. I will change that. But you are completely wrong when you say `There is nothing special at all in the Romanian name of Wales.`  I am not aware of any other language where the name for Wales includes the name for Gauls., and where that doesn't follow the name of the people (a correction was made for that, but only for that). **Are you*? -  - By the way, even if you were correct, my question is still justified (but maybe not on this site and not with great chance of being answered).

Comment: @melissa_boiko - Even worse `everybody calls them *walhaz, subject to local sound changes.` **Nobody** calls them walaz now! That is the old root for terms that now refer to different peoples, **mean** different things. And the change is not just local, is historical, chronological, etymological. Does "Roman" mean the same as "Romanian" in any language? Even in Romanian "roman" and "român" are more different than Bulgar and Bulgarian in English. Can we call the Welsh Waloons or Galicians?  NO.

Answer (score 1):

Your theory can well explain why the name stuck, but assumption of an ignorant scribe would need more evidence to be convincing. It's not very likely in matters of hegemony. The assumption of public indifference can explain why the name stuck, at last.

The possibility that the name were inhereted of old can't be discounted either. Late attestation usually counts in favor of a recent coinage. But Rumanian is "rather poorly attested" overall. One has to wonder by what other names the country had been called in Rumanian, or why not. If the construction, "tara ..." had seemed familiar, wonder whether it hadn't been used elsewhere; Latin "tera ..." is a frequent metonym, I think. The focus is not on *tara*, though.

In sum, the importance that onomastics has for tribal movements and history in general makes it well worth to backproject the name speculatively.

Asking for a first never makes sense. You mean *at the latest*.

For some speculation, consider that the Polish L with a strike through is close to /w/ (which if rounded is close to /u/, hence double-u; Italic L is also close to V and C in shape, with different orientation), but ignorantly transliterated as L often enough. So, maybe you are actually looking at *gawilor*! Polish is far from the Balkans, but there's a Pomak minority, for one. And Kiew and Prag had been powerhouses before (but I know nothing about their ells and ues). Otherwise, consider Latin transcription *Guilhelm* for *Willhelm* and the like. But French writes *gui* for /gi/ today, to disambiguae *gi* /ji/, though strictly *ga* /ga/, *ja* /.../. Youknow.

This is a non- answer, I'm aware. My answer is: It was first mentioned in speech, long before it was written down, but there is no way to know. I'm aware that's not satisfying.

Comment: `You mean at the latest.` - What I mean is `when the term was first attested in Romanian` but I would be amazed if it were before modern 19th century journalism.  There was no direct contact with the British before that. - I have asked here because I haven't found a Romanian language site where I could hope for an answer (until [this](https://www.scientia.ro/qa/26438/cand-a-fost-pentru-prima-oara-tradus-numele-wales-in-limba-romana-sub-forma-tara-galilor)), but anyway anywhere chances for an answer are slim. I was about to delete the Q but I had the bounty. Thanks for your interest! :)